# passing id information with ajax

Tags: php, ajax

hi I am trying to identify the table id in a SQL query command.

here is my query command:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
    $query = " UPDATE cursos
           SET status = '$checkboxstatus'
           WHERE id='$id'";
```

all that code is inside a backend.php file which is loaded trought ajax command from the main php file:

this is the AJAX script which I am using:

```
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
$('input[name=status]').change(function(){
    if( $('input[name=status]').prop('checked') )
       {checkboxstatus = '1';}
       else
       {checkboxstatus = '0';}
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "checkboxtestbackend.php",
        data: {checkboxstatus: checkboxstatus},
```

the question is for the record to be inserted in the right field inside the database I Have to put inside $id the id of the element from the sql dump which is done on this page.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{   $id = $row['id'];
?><?php echo "<input type='checkbox' id='$id' name='status'"; if($row['status'] == 1){print "checked='checked'"; }echo "/>";
```

what I think is that I have to send in this command             `data: {checkboxstatus: checkboxstatus},` also the id but how this can be done ? or if there is a better way let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not posting "id".

Insert this

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
```

before  `$.ajax({`

Now, Use this

```
data: {"checkboxstatus": checkboxstatus,
        "id":id 
       },
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('input[name=status]').change(function(){
        if ( this.checked ) {
            checkboxstatus = '1';
        } else {
            checkboxstatus = '0';
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "checkboxtestbackend.php",
            data: {
                checkboxstatus: checkboxstatus,
                id: this.id
            },
```

`this` is the element that was clicked on.

Notice that I had to change how you set `checkboxstatus`. You were always getting the status of the first checkbox, not the one that was changed.

Answer (score 0):

You could also post the ID

```
data: {checkboxstatus: checkboxstatus,id: $('input[name=status]').attr('id') },
```